# SSL certificate error while securing nifi with ranger

Tags: apache-nifi

I am using HDF 3.0

I create keystore and truststore certificate with path and mention in Nifi ranger policy. While I test the connection I got an issue that I have shown below. I follow this link [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/58769/hdf-20-enable-ranger-authorization-for-hdf-compone.html)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

NiFi is secured using TLS certificates. When installed and secured via Ambari, by default Ambari installs a NiFi Certificate Authority (CA) and will generate certificates for each NiFi node and get those certificates signed by that CA.
The NiFI node private key is loaded in the keystore.jks file of each NiFi Node and the public key for the CA is loaded in the truststore.jks file on each NiFi node.
When a client (Ranger in the above case is the client) initiates a connection to NiFi, a two-way TLS connection is negotiated. This involves the server sending the node's public key (derived from the certificate in the keystore.jks) to the client. The client will check that key against a list of trustedCertEntries in its truststore.jks file. If it finds the servers public key or the public key of the CA who signed that server key in the truststore.jks, it will trusted the cert provided by the server. The client will then provide its client certificate (derived from ranger keystore.jks private key) to the target NiFi node. NiFi will follow the same steps above to determine if it should trusted the cert provided from that client using its truststore.jks file.
The error you are seeing indicates that this two-way TLS negotiating is failing because Ranger does not trust the cert being presented by NiFi. If you get past this, you will like have failure of trust the other way as well. You need to make sure the truststore.jks used by both NiFi's nodes and Ranger contains all the necessary "trustedCertEntries" for both sides of this connection. (This means having the public key of the NiFi CA loaded in Ranger's truststore.jks file and loading the public key for your Ranger certificate in the truststore.jks file used by your NiFi instances.

Comment: Instead of copy-pasting from online, please post a reference to the original link/resource, in this case it is: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/117754/ssl-certificate-while-securing-nifi-with-ranger.html